# Single client accessing multiple resources in Oauth2 Spring-Security-OAuth

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I've been using Spring OAuth2 for some time now. It works great. Recently there has been a need to add an additional service and one of the existing clients needs to access that new service.

My setup is as follows

service1 (Spring Boot micro-service)
service2 (Spring Boot micro-service)
Authorization Service (a separate Spring Boot micro-service)

Currently, in the oauth_client_details db table the client is configured as follows

client_id | resource_ids | ...
myClient  | service1

Adding the resource id as below doesn't work

myClient | service1, service2

What am I missing here? And what is the proper way to configure a single client for accessing multiple resources?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For others who have the same issue as I, what you need to do is to delete the current token value and obtain/generate a new token. This was my issue.